# How to do inclusion of schema in other schema using Z language

Tags: z-notation

I am writing a formal specification for my model using z-notation of Z-language. I am stuck and don't know how to include one schema in another schema and creates its variables in other schemas. Any guidance and help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a schema like a record data type. E.g. let's assume you have a schema describing a complex integer number:

```
--- Complex ---
| real, img: ℤ
------
```

You can declare a variable in another schema to be of that type:

```
--- Ex1 ---
| c: Complex
----
| c.real = 5 ∧ c.img = 6
-------
```

You can of course create more complex data types with it, here a sequence and an operation to append an element:

```
--- State ---
| data: seq Complex
-------

--- Add1 ---
| ΔState
| real?, img?: ℤ
----
| ∃ c:Complex · c.real = real? ∧ c.img = img? ∧ data' = data^<c>
-------
```

You can also use the theta-operator to create an instance of that type. The values for the variables are taken from the current context (+ optional decorations):

```
--- Add2 ---
| ΔState
| real?, img?: ℤ
----
| data' = data^< θComplex? >
-------
```

`θComplex?` is an instance of `Complex` where the values for `real` and `img` are taken from the local variables `real?` and `img?`.

We can also declare the input variables by using the original schema and write the operation more concise (Add3 is the same as Add2):

```
--- Add3 ---
| ΔState
| Complex?
----
| data' = data^< θComplex? >
-------
```

(I deleted my original answer because I misinterpret your question.)

Comment: danielp , you guided me in a right direction. Now the only thing which is still confusing me. how can we declare this variable as a collection of that schema? That is, can we use Fat F to represent a finite collection of that schema.

Comment: @YasirDarr: Yes, you can declare it exactly like the sequence above, just use  Complex instead of seq Complex. Like you did in your additional answer.

Comment: Alright dear, Now it seems that I will be able to solve my issue. (y)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
--- Agent---
| state: AgentState
-------

--- Shape ---
| agents :F Agent
----
| ∃ agt:agents · agt.state = stationary                                                         
 -------
```